# How to use the HTML5 Boilerplate ir class with inline elements?

Tags: css, html5boilerplate, image-replacement

I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate css and I would like to apply the `ir` class to my footer menu.
The menu is in a list, and I use inline-block to display this list horizontally.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt8Qe/) of the code. You can see that the image replacement works, but the text menu element after (that has no image) is translated to the bottom. This is due to the `.ir:before` css rule that simulate a block element which takes some room.

Is there a way to use the HTML5 Boilerplate technique without this side-effect ?
If not, I will go back to the `text-indent:-9999px` technique.

Bonus question : what are the benefits of the HTML5 Boilerplate technique compared to the text-indent one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text-indent: -9999px` method has some drawbacks. The main are:

- does not work in IE6 and IE7 on inline-block elements.
- 1st gen. iPads have proven to have performance issues with this technique, with page rendering slowing down quite a bit.
- Even if we don't see it, any browser in any device has to draw a huge div (more than 9999px) that overflows the screen. This is **bad** for performance as it adds page load time and requires more memory resources.

The `.ir` technique in HTML5 Boilerplate has proven much more performant and reliable. You're doing the right thing.

Having said that, I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve in your code. I have restructered the html a bit in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Kt8Qe/1/).

As you can see I have put red borders to understand where exactly elements are and how much space they take up. Every image/text is now in its own `<li>` which is semantically logic (one link/one list item), like so:

```
 <ul>
     <li>facebook<li>
     <li>twitter</li>
     <li>example page</li>
 <ul>
```

I've also removed the `float:left` to the nav as you need to float the elements inside it, not the container itself. Hope this clears it up a bit and helps you get to where you want. I'm ready to edit this answer if any improvement is needed or if I have misunderstood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Nobita for your answer. I just have two concerns : I need the double list for the text menu element for further styling that I don't mentioned to make it simpler. I also need to have all the element centered vertically. I modified the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt8Qe/2/) to fix that.

Comment: To sum up, I think my issue were that the <a> elements with `ir` class  should have been wrapped into their own <li> to achieve a clean layout.