# boilerplate - Image replacement does not work with inline-block on IE7

Tags: html, boilerplate

I'm using html5 boilerplate. On IE 7, image replacement does not seem to work with A href that uses inline-block. I just get a blank image.  However if i use inline-block on a paragraph, element it works.

what is the correct syntax for using image-replacement in boilerplate?

```
<h1><a href="#" class="ir">Title</a></h1>
```

or

```
<h1 class="ir"><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336367/how-to-use-the-html5-boilerplate-ir-class-with-inline-elements

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the second one. `ir` class is modifying the h1 element. The documentation says:

`Add the .ir class to any element you are applying image-replacement to. When replacing an element's content with an image, make sure to also set a specific background-image: url(pathtoimage.png);, width, and height so that your replacement image appears.`

so it kind of makes sense to apply to h1 element rather than to anchor element.

Comment: Okay thanks!  I think the problem with IE had to do with IE 7 not knowhing how to layout inline-block correctly. Strangely none of my ie7 hacks worked to get IR working.

Comment: Maybe this simple hack will work in your favor: http://adriandalvarez.tumblr.com/post/6731022156/html5-boilerplate-image-replacement-helper-class-ie7